# memory limit exceeded while using comparator function

Tags: function, memory, comparator

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
bool compaa(int i,int j)
{
    if((i%2)!=0)
return true;
else
return false;
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        long long int a[n],i,count=0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin>>a[i];
        }
        sort(a,a+n,compaa);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cout<<a[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

above code is giving memory limit exceeded. it is using more than 262100 KB of memory.
But if I do a slight change the code runs just fine consuming only 3600 KB of memory.
why is this happening??
below is the code which works just fine:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
bool compaa(int i,int j)
{
return (i%2)>(j%2);
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        long long int a[n],i,count=0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin>>a[i];
        }
        sort(a,a+n,compaa);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cout<<a[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what is happening with comparator function?

Comment: DON'T use `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. Also, `long long int a[n]` with `n` not know at compile time is not standard C++.

Comment: Please provide input values for your program (`t`, `n`) to make the problem reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ standard, the function used for comparison must be a

> comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare) which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.

"requirements of Compare" are these: the comparison function must

> Establish **strict weak ordering** relation with the following properties:
> For all `a`, `comp(a,a)==false`
> If `comp(a,b)==true` then `comp(b,a)==false`
> if `comp(a,b)==true` and `comp(b,c)==true` then `comp(a,c)==true`

Now, let's check your 1st attempt at comparison function:

```
bool compaa(int i, int j)
{
    if ((i % 2) != 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

`compaa(2,2)` returns `false` as it should.  But `compaa(1,1)` returns `true`

The other 2 conditions are also violated.

You can check that the second version,

```
bool compaa(int i, int j)
{
  return (i % 2) > (j % 2);
}
```

satisfies all conditions of  strict weak ordering: the numbers are ordered according to their remainders modulo 2.

Other remarks:

- Please don't submit programs with `std::cin` and without the numbers that need to be entered to reproduce your problem.

Further reading:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare